# Setting rhoend parameter with lme4

Tags: r, lme4, mixed-models

I am running a `lmer` model, with `verbose = 2L`, as in the following simple example:

```
library(lme4)
myData <- data.frame(Y = rnorm(100), 
                     Group = sample(LETTERS[1:2], 100, replace = TRUE))
LMER <- lmer(Y ~ (1 | Group), data = myData, verbose = 2L)
```

The verbose output looks like this:

```
npt = 3 , n =  1 
rhobeg =  0.2 , rhoend =  2e-07 
   0.020:   6:      293.717;0.200000 
  0.0020:   8:      293.684;0.166601 
 0.00020:  12:      293.683;0.160047 
 2.0e-05:  14:      293.683;0.160260 
 2.0e-06:  15:      293.683;0.160260 
 2.0e-07:  17:      293.683;0.160254 
At return
 20:     293.68311: 0.160254
```

I would like to change the `rhoend` parameter, with the idea of reducing the amount of time it takes to fit, presumably at the expense of getting less precise estimates.

How can I re-write my `lmer()` call to alter the `rhoend` parameter?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like this:

See `?lmerControl`: you need to put the `rhoend` setting inside a list called `optCtrl`, to be passed to the optimizer.

```
LMER2 <- lmer(Y ~ (1 | Group), data = myData, 
  verbose = 2L, control=lmerControl(optCtrl=list(rhoend=1e-5)))
npt = 3 , n =  1 
rhobeg =  0.03090896 , rhoend =  1e-05 
start par. =  0.1545448 fn =  314.382 
rho:   0.0031 eval:   3 fn:      314.382 par:0.154545 
rho:  0.00031 eval:   5 fn:      314.380 par:0.165471 
rho:  5.6e-05 eval:   7 fn:      314.380 par:0.164620 
rho:  1.0e-05 eval:   9 fn:      314.380 par:0.164573 
At return
eval:  10 fn:      314.37951 par: 0.164571
```

You could also consider using `control=lmerControl(optimizer="nloptwrap")` in the latest (1.1-7) version of `lme4` -- by default it uses a different implementation of the BOBYQA optimizer. See the examples in `?nloptwrap` to see that you can change the tolerances for changes in the parameters (`xtol_abs`) or the response (`ftol_abs`).  The default tolerances for `nloptwrap` are somewhat milder (= faster run times) than those for the default optimizer.

By the way, my answers are quite different from yours because we picked different random numbers.  Best to use `set.seed(101)` (or some other arbitrary integer of your choice) for reproducibility.